# addAttributeToSelect() does not work for newly created attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, product-collection, bug

I had to create a product collection that contains some newly created attributes. It was not possible to add these attributes to the collection *('inner' doesn't make a difference)*. Even **reindexing didn't help**.

### Example code:

```
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$attributes = array(
    'name',
    'new_attribute'
);
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes, 'inner');
```

Query for that collection:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_name`.`value` AS `name`, `at_new_attribute`.`value` AS `new_attribute`
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name`
    ON (`at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_name`.`attribute_id` = '71') AND (`at_name`.`store_id` = 0)
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_new_attribute`
    ON (`at_new_attribute`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_new_attribute`.`attribute_id` = '514') AND (`at_new_attribute`.`store_id` = 0)
```

If i check for that attribute_id 514 in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` I get also an empty result. So neither `null` nor the "default value" is set.

```
SELECT *
FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar`
WHERE attribute_id = 514
```

> MySQL returned an empty result set

After using workaround from below I get 750 correct results *(with value `null`)*.

Even when you set a "default value" for this newly created attribute, it is not populated to products when you add it to attribute set. The "default value" is only used if you create new products.

### Steps to reproduce:

1. add new attribute *(use in product listing doesn't matter)*
2. assign attribute to attribute set
3. reindex attributes/flat tables
4. run code

**Expected result:**

Get a collection where `$item->getNewAttribute()` is `null` or empty string.

**Current result:**

Get an empty collection. *(`$products->getSize()` is 0)*

---

### Workaround:

Fortunately i found an answer here: [When setting a product attribute programmatically, can't retrieve it from a collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137126/when-setting-a-product-attribute-programmatically-cant-retrieve-it-from-a-coll/137258#137258)

1. open product grid
2. select all
3. update attributes
4. submit
5. check "change" checkbox for "attributecode" attribute but leave input field empty
6. save

---

For my understanding attribute values (`null` or "default value") should be added to DB when assing a attribute to a set, but it doesn't happen. Products only appear in product collection, if:

- product is saved manually, **or**
- workaround is used (for multible products)

**Any ideas where to fix this in code?**

Comment: do reindexing and try again

Comment: As said reindexing didnt help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get theme in your collection because, Only the attributes that are marked `be used in product listing` to **YES** are copyed to the flat tables. Mark it like this in `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > {select your attribute}`, reindex everything and now you have your attributes.

**EDIT:**

It should work by doing this config! anyway if you don't set `used in product listing` to **yes**, You will never get the attributes in the collection, i explained you because for doing this config, Magento copyed them to the flat tables. **and don't forget to reindex all !**

Maybe you have some issue in your collection, try this one:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'yourattribute'));
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: The attributes, you created them in the backoffice?

Comment: Yes, created from backend.

Comment: So it should work ! anyway if you don't set `used in product listing` to yes, You will never get the attributes in the collection, i explained you because for doing this config, Magento copyed them to the flat tables.

Comment: Please, look my update

Comment: Thanks again, but this is not related to "use in product listing" and flat tables aren't used here. Check added query in question.

Answer (score 0):

can't use

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

because in 'app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php' function addAttributeToSelect called isEnabledFlat

```
    public function isEnabledFlat()
{
    // Flat Data can be used only on frontend
    if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you assign that manage attribute set if not assign so assign it.

Comment: Assign attribute to attribute set? Done before. This behavoir is confirmed in the linked question.

Comment: Downvote. I just can run "Update attributes" on assigned attributes (step 3).