# can't filter collection by custom attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, product-collection, custom-attributes

I have a custom attribute called parent_sku, I setted it to `yes` in `Product Listing` from the backend menu, and almost all the products have a value in this attribute.

I tried:

```
$subCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('id','parent_sku'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_sku', array('eq' => $parent_sku));
```

I also tried (I know it is the same):

```
$subCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('id','parent_sku'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_sku', $parent_sku));
```

$parent_sku has a valid value, that is the same of the value that have some of the products in parent_sku attribute.

But I get always $subCollection empty.

```
count($subCollection)  // this is always zero
```

[image: paren_sku custom attribute configuration]

Comment: If it's a new attribute, please check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178259/addattributetoselect-does-not-work-for-newly-created-attributes Maybe the posted workaround solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. After adding your attribute, you should to **reindexAll**
2. Try this:

   ```
   $subCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'parent_sku'));
   ```
3. Clear your browser and Magento cache.

Comment: It is no new attribute, it's been there for a while. However after reindexing I can getParentSku() with no problem.

Comment: Yes, I knew it that's why I mentioned it First

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code:

```
$subCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('parent_sku', $parent_sku);
```

Comment: I think it's `addAttributeToFilter` for product collections, not `addFieldToFilter`

Comment: I still get no parent_sku in the collection, I tried addAttributeToSelect and addFieldToFilter with '*' and with array('id','parent_sku') but I still can't get the parent_sku custom attribute in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$subCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('parent_sku', array('eq' => $parent_sku))
        ->load();
```

Comment: I tried the load at the end, but still no parent_skull custom attribute in the collection